# Trailhead question about why value for outputNumber isn't updating as they request?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, trailhead

[Developer Intermediate > Lightning Components > Using JavaScript Controllers With Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lightning_components/lightning_components_js)

The error that Trailhead is giving me is that "Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: The client side controller does not set a value for the outputNumber component".... BUT based on when I plug this into an app and run it, it sure appears that the value for outputNumber is being set.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the Component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="total" type="Integer" default="0"/>
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="inputOne" label="Enter 1"/>
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="inputTwo" label="Enter 2"/>
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="inputThree" label="Enter 3"/>
    <ui:button label="Submit" press="{!c.calculate}"/>
    <ui:outputNumber aura:id="totalValue" value="{!v.total}"/>
</aura:component>
```

and here is the controller:

```
({
    calculate : function(component, event, helper) {
        var inputOne = parseInt(component.find("inputOne").get("v.value"));

        var inputTwo = parseInt(component.find("inputTwo").get("v.value"));
        var inputThree = parseInt(component.find("inputThree").get("v.value"));
        var total = inputOne + inputTwo - inputThree;
        if (isNaN(total)){
            component.set("v.errors", [{message:"Total not a number: " + total}]);
        } else {
            component.set("v.total", total);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Trailhead developer forum may be right place for this to quickly get attention from Trailhead team .I will remove if and else since error handling is not asked in challenge and check challenge .Thanks

Comment: I tried there... nobody responded and I just am so stuck on this one, it is frustrating me.

Comment: Can you post the question link here and we tweet Trailhead team to get some help

Comment: Here is where it is in the Trailhead Q is https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000BZsbIAG

Comment: Are you on twitter ? I just pinged Trailhead Team to help us with this .Thanks

Comment: You da real MVP. @notthehoff

Comment: Trailhead has replied to your query https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000BZsbIAG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross Posting the answer from Dev forum

In your component, try changing your totalValue provider to:

```
<ui:outputNumber aura:id="totalValue" value="" />
```

And also in your Js controller use the below

```
component.find("totalValue").set("v.value",total);
```

But your original solution is correct no doubt .This is because Trailhead challenge looks for specific things .Also note Find via Aura Id is one of the best practices when accessing element .

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. Take a look at your definition for `ui:outputNumber` in your component. What are you "outputting"? Now look at your controller and think about what you're passing back to it. We have a rule here in this forum that we don't provide solutions to Trailhead questions. However, this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: > What am I outputting? v.total... it appears on the screen.  What is the controller passing back to the screen? it is setting v.total to be total.

I am confused on what is wrong, as it actually is outputting the thing it is specifically asking for, but just ...apparently... not in the way they want?

Comment: @notthehoff Your code looks correct to me but may not be same as that of whats expected .So lets get this sorted with Trailhead team

Comment: As a side note, I did remove the if/else, as your comment did make sense.... didn't help

Comment: That was a step in the right direction, but think in terms of "returning" what you were "getting". What's the name of that "v." variable?

Comment: Technically, I am not returning anything... I am setting v.total to total and then ui:outputNumber is dynamically changing to what the total attribute is set to.

Comment: Let's put it this way, are you sure you should be setting "v.total" to "total" or vice versa actually?